# Nested Interval Property and Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, infinity, natural-numbers

I'm having difficulty understanding some of the properties of real numbers which invoke infinity. For example, the fact that $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) = \emptyset$$
What confuses me about this is that it seems that it can be proven to be *false* for arbitrarly large natural numbers. I considered something like this:

Consider the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^{m}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Due to the desnity of the rationals, for any interval there exists a value c such that $0 < \frac{1}{c} < \frac{1}{n}$. So every interval $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ is non-empty. Now, choose c such that $0<\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{m}$. Since $\frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{m-1} < ... < \frac{1}{1}$, then, since $\frac{1}{c}$ is in every interval, then $\frac{1}{c} \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{m}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Since m was an arbitrarily chosen natural number, this should hold for an arbitrarily large natural number.

But, I know that the intersection over all natural number is the empty set, and that means that something must be different between an arbitrarily large natural number and iterating over the *entire* set of natural numbers.

This breaks my intuition, and I realize I don't have an accurate and rigorous conception of infinity. For example, here are some central questions that I'm unsure how to answer:

1. What is wrong with viewing infinity as some arbitrarily large natural number?
2. How would I prove that while I can always create a smaller fraction than $\frac{1}{n}$ by constructing $\frac{1}{n+1}$, there isn't a fraction between $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ 'at infinity'?

I would appreciate advice on how I should intuitively view infinity, especially regarding the difference between something holding true for an arbitrarily large number but failing 'at infinity.' Thank you for your time!

Comment: "Infinity" and "arbitrarily large" are very different sizes.  If you spend a zillion millennia counting to some arbitrarily large number, you will have barely started counting to infinity.

Comment: You might want to utilize the definition of the intersection over a collection of sets, $$x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \iff x\in A_i, \space \forall i\in I$$ Clearly there exists an interval $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ such that $\frac{1}{c}\not\in (0,\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Your second point is related to Archimedean property.

Comment: The answer to your second question depends on how you define real numbers.

Comment: I would also note that the statement $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) = \emptyset$ does not actually contain "$\infty$" in it anywhere.  You seem to be trying to understand it as some sort of "infinite limiting case" of $\bigcap_{n=1}^{m}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$, but there's no need to do so.  Just directly apply the definition of an intersection, as in RyanK's comment.  If this doesn't match your intuition of what "infinity" should mean, that's totally fine; just think of it as defining something else.

Comment: @EricWofsey I guess I misunderstood exactly what $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$ means. I had thought that was to be interpeted as (or at least equivalent to) $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$$. Ignoring that my example I provided in the question might be mistaken, the same sort of thing happens in other circumstances. A much more direct example would be that the sum of an arbitrarily large number of natural numbers is a natural number, but if you add an infinite number of them the value is not a natural number. What confuses me, is that you could use induction to show that n is a natural number...

Comment: @EricWofsey [Continuing my previous comment]...n is a natural number implies that n+1 is a natural number (pretty much by definition). But, that seems to mean that I can add +1 as many times as the size of the natural numbers, since "n+1 is a natural number" holds for a set that is the size of the natural numbers. Yet, at some point, n+1 is not a natural number anymore. Certainly for any natural number $\frac{1}{n}$ exists, and that seems that would imply $\frac{1}{n+1}$ exists, but somehow at some point there is no $\frac{1}{n+1}$ that lies between $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ That is where I'm confused

Comment: $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is just a notation, though.  It doesn't imply that $\infty$ has any particular meaning.  Similarly, when you talk about "adding infinitely many natural numbers", the question is what do you even *mean* by that addition?  Talking about infinite operations like this has no *intrinsic* meaning; it only has a meaning if we define it in some way.  And our definition will be a perfectly precise logical definition that does not actually refer to "infinity", so you can just use that definition and never think about infinity.

Comment: The primary source of confusion lies about the counter-intuitive desire to know "what happens at infinity". Well, in the standard analysis every thing happens using finite numbers and using finite arguments we try to deal with infinite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've shown some confusion about it in the comments, let's start with the meaning of $$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty A_n = \bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} A_n$$
The definition of the first expression is the second (not vice versa). And the definition of the second is
$$\bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} A_n = \{a\mid \forall n \in \Bbb N, a \in A_n\}$$
There is no taking of limits here, and no approximations. It is simple logic: To be in the interesection, it has to be in *every* set.

The real numbers $\Bbb R$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) complete ordered field. "Ordered field" just means a set with addition and multiplication behaving normally, and an order operation $\le$ that respects the addition and multiplication. By "complete" I mean that the order has the supremum property: If non-empty $A \subset \Bbb R$ is bounded above, then it has a supremum, or least upper bound. Lets play with that:

First, if $\Bbb N$ is bounded above, then it has a supremum $\omega \in \Bbb R$. But then $\omega -1 < \omega$ is not an upper bound, so there must be some $n \in \Bbb N$ with $ n > \omega -1$, and therefore $n + 1 > \omega$. Since $n+1 \in \Bbb N$, this contradicts that $\omega$ is an upper bound. Therefore $\Bbb N$ cannot be bounded. And so for every $x \in \Bbb R$, there is an $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n > x$, the "Archimedean principle".

But then if $\epsilon > 0$, it is invertible, and there is some $n > \frac 1\epsilon$. And that means $\frac 1n < \epsilon$. So for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $n \in \Bbb N$ with $\frac 1n < \epsilon$.

If $x \in \bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} \left(0,\frac 1n\right)$, then $x \in (0,1)$. So $x > 0$. And for all $n, x \in \left(0,\frac 1n\right)$, so for all $n, x < \frac 1n$, in contradiction to the previous result. Hence there cannot be such an $x$, so $$\bigcap_{n\in \Bbb N} \left(0,\frac 1n\right) =\varnothing$$